# Backbone Marionette composite view is not showing rows in the table

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am new to both backbone and marionette.
Here is my current progress.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Marionette composite view test</title>

    <script src="./assets/libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/backbone.marionette.js"></script>

    <link href="./assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script type="text/template" id="fDD">
        <td><%= subtype %></td>
        <td><%= acs_code %></td>
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="fD">
    <caption><%= name %> ( <%= rollnum %> ), Project Code(<%= projectcode %>)</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Submission Type </th>
                <th> Access number </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="sub-Region">
        </tbody>        
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {"name": "Mr XYZ", "rollnum": "53", "projectcode": "3526",
                "submissions": [{"subtype": "A5", "acs_code": "5689-64123"},
                {"subtype": "A8", "acs_code": "5689-64122"},
                {"subtype": "D1", "acs_code": "5689-64122"},
                {"subtype": "A5", "acs_code": "5689-64122"}]}

    MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    MyApp.addRegions({
      mainRegion: "#content"
    });

    Submission = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    Submissions = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Submission
    });

    SubmissionInfo = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    MainInfo = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: SubmissionInfo
    });


    FilingView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: "tr",
        template: "#fDD"

    });   

    TableView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
       tagName: "table",
       itemView: FilingView,
       template: "#fD",
       itemViewContainer: "#sub-Region",
       className: "table table-hover table-condensed"
    });

    AccordionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
      itemView: TableView
    }); 

    MyApp.addInitializer(function(options){
    var mainInfo = new MainInfo(options.data);
    mainInfo.each(function(iinfo){
        var ss = iinfo.get("submissions");
        var sss = new Submissions({collection: ss});
        iinfo.set("submissions", sss);
    });

    MyApp.mainRegion.show(new AccordionView({collection: mainInfo}));
    });

    MyApp.start({data: data});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to render a table in which i will show some info in its caption and other details as its rows. But only caption part is rendering while rows are missing. even that is without any error. How to solve this?? any better way to achieve this???

For above code; i am using: 
Backbone.js 1.0.0 
MarionetteJS  v1.0.3 
jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1 
Underscore.js 1.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some basic mistakes: how you should initialize a collection, the correct constructors of backbone objects, etc. Below is a working version of your code.

```
<script type="text/template" id="fDD">
    <td><%= subtype %></td>
    <td><%= acs_code %></td>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="fD">
    <caption><%= name %> ( <%= rollnum %> ), Project Code(<%= projectcode %>)</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Submission Type </th>
        <th> Access number </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="sub-Region">
    </tbody>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {"name": "Mr XYZ", "rollnum": "53", "projectcode": "3526",
        "submissions": [{"subtype": "A5", "acs_code": "5689-64123"},
            {"subtype": "A8", "acs_code": "5689-64122"},
            {"subtype": "D1", "acs_code": "5689-64122"},
            {"subtype": "A5", "acs_code": "5689-64122"}]};

    MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    MyApp.addRegions({
        mainRegion: "#content"
    });

    var Submission = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    var SubmissionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Submission
    });

    var Project = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    var FilingView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: "tr",
        template: "#fDD"

    });

    var TableView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        tagName: "table",
        itemView: FilingView,
        template: "#fD",
        itemViewContainer: "#sub-Region",
        className: "table table-hover table-condensed"
    });

    MyApp.addInitializer(function(options){
        var projectInfo = new Project(options.data);
        var submissions = new SubmissionCollection(projectInfo.get("submissions"));

        MyApp.mainRegion.show(new TableView({model: projectInfo, collection: submissions}));
    });

    MyApp.start({data: data});
</script>
</body>
```